# The custom middleware is not working in the controller (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I did a custom middleware to handle the auth api token and I call this middleware in the controller, but it's not working I added dd('') inside the middleware to see if it displays anything and it did not worked.

My middleware is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use App\ApiUser;

class ApiAuth
{
/**
 * Run the request filter.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $var)
{
   dd('If I put this dd it does not display anything');

    $api_user_count = ApiAuth::where('api_token', $var)->count();

    if($api_user_count == 0)
    {
        abort(403, "Auth failed")
    }
    
    return $next($request)
 }
}
```

My controller is, how you can see I am sending a parameter to the middleware:

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware('apiauth:'.$request->api_token);

    $transaction = new Transaction;

    $transaction->folio = $request->folio;

    $transaction->dte_code = $request->dte_code;

    $transaction->cashier = $request->cashier;

    $transaction->amount = $request->amount;

    if($transaction->save())
    {
        return response()->json('Ok', 201);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json('Error', 400);
    }
}
```

I put the middleware in the path App\Http\Middleware\ApiAuth.php

I put the middleware in the kernel.php like this:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'apiauth' => \App\Http\Middleware\ApiAuth::class, // THIS IS THE MINE
];
```

The weird thing is that it does not display any error, it's like it does not exist so I wonder what it's wrong with this?

Thanks!

Comment: you have access to the request in the middleware so you dont need to pass a parameter to it that is from the request ... the `middleware` method on the controller just adds to an array on the controller, it does not "run" anything

Comment: @lagbox but the weird thing is that I can not see the dd('') inside the middleware it looks like it's not working at all

Comment: because it isn't running the middleware, calling the `middleware` method on the controller does not "run" any middleware it just registers it, and it is done in the constructor not in random methods ... the framework will get an instance of the controller so it can then get what middleware was declared in its constructor so it can build the middleware stack

Comment: @lagbox how can I fix it?

Comment: @JesúsCova remove this line `$this->middleware('apiauth:'.$request->api_token);
` from the `store()` method. instead apply the middleware in the `__construct` method of your controller . see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439859/the-custom-middleware-is-not-working-in-the-controller-laravel/63439905#63439905)

Answer (score 1):

instead of calling the middleware manually from your controller method you can register the middleware to apply only for that one method

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('apiauth')->only(['store']);
}
```

then you can extract the `api_token` from `$request`

```
$api_user_count = ApiAuth::where('api_token', $request-> api_token)->get()->count();
```

Comment: I can not even see a dd('')

Comment: calling a middleware like this from controller method `$this->middleware('apiauth:'.$request->api_token);`is not correct. check the edited answer.